# How to call vector size as a function?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to show a size of a vector by calling corresponding function `totalVectorSize(myVector)`.

I get "cannot convert vector to integer" error, what am I doing wrong?

Declaration

```
vector<int> myVector; 
int totalVectorSize(myVector);
```

main()

```
int main() {

int vectorSize=5;
cout << "Enter " << vectorSize <<" integers: " << endl;
int Vector,i;
```

I am filling up the vector here:

```
for (i=0; i<vectorSize; i++){
    cin >> Vector;
    myVector.push_back(Vector);
}
```

I want to show the vector's size by calling `totalVectorSize(myVector)` function.

```
int total;
total = totalVectorSize(myVector);
cout << total;

}
```

The `totalVectorSize(myVector)` function is:

```
int totalVectorSize(myVector){
  cout << "Total number of elements in this vector is " << myVector.size();
return total
}
```

Comment: Remove `using std;` from your code!

Comment: `totalVectorSize` can literally just `return myVector.size();`. But even then, you can just get the size directly without going through a wrapper function. i.e. `int total = myVector.size();` And if you want to be extra careful that any conversions between `std::vector<int>::size_type` and `int` on your implementation don't cause any undesired effects, you can use `auto`.

Comment: And add a data type to the parameter to this `int totalVectorSize(myVector);`

Comment: If it is just for `myVector`, don't even need to receive arguments, just `int totalVectorSize()`, because ´myVector` is global.

Comment: The one and only correct answer: Use [`std::vector::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) without an extra function.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Invited you in case you want to contribute constructively at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user40 You'll want to take a look at a C++ tutorial. There are plenty scattered across the internet and in books; it's not a language you can guess your way into. For example, a C++ tutorial would have introduced vectors, which I'm guessing you have serious misunderstandings about, as well as telling you the correct syntax for declaring functions -- things like that you have to include the arguments' types.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do:

```
int total = myVector.size();
```

If you need to also display the size (and you still want to use a function for this - for learning purposes, I presume), you would have to fix your function:

```
// declaration:
int totalVectorSize(const vector<int>& vec);

// implementation:
int totalVectorSize(const vector<int>& vec) {
    int vecSize = vec.size();
    cout << "Total number of elements in this vector is " << vecSize;
    return vecSize;
}
```

I added passing the vector by const reference because there is no need to copy an entire vector just to get it's size.

Also, `int` is not the best type to be used for storing size in this example, but let's leave it at that for now.

Comment: I don't see what value `totalVectorSize()` would gain over simply using `vec.size()` directly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "I don't see what value totalVectorSize() would gain over simply using vec.size() directly. " side effects: logging, instrumentation (timing or whatnot), notifying observers somebody asked for the size of a vector.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh, you mighty repository of categorical and definitive answers, so I'll do, so I'll do.